# Redirect to HTTPS Error - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, ssl, https

We've a problem trying to redirect the user from http to https - Both works and https is using ssl and working flawless.

When we're trying to redirect the user with different methods we keep getting this error:
**ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

The methods we have tried..

- htaccess
- Applying a global filter in MVC
- Attributes in the controller (RequireHttpsAttribute)
- Web.config (Rewrite Rules)

It's the same result for the 404-page that doesn't use a controller.

Comment: It looks like the error has come because of some infinite loop being called. HTTP to HTTPS and back to HTTP.

Comment: Thanks Sirish.

I know there is a infinity loop, but I don't really know what is causing it. It's the same error with different methods.

Is it possible the webserver/hostprovider can have anything to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide how you are doing the redirect. Are you in a web farm? Is SSL offloaded to a load balancer?

In certain cloud/hosting scenarios, the latter is the possible culprit  -

e.g.

- in your *application*, you're checking for an SSL connection and the application tries to redirect to an `https` url (i.e. `HttpRequest.IsSecureConnection`)
- however, if a load balancer handles SSL for your server**s** (farm), the connection from the load balancer to your host**s** may not be via `https` - and there's your loop (the ssl check in your application will always be `false`)

  `browser: https` < - > `SSL/Load Balancer` < - - > `web farm: http`

  in this scenario check with your provider - they *usually* will have *custom headers* that you can inspect when they forward the request to your server**s** indicating that the original request *was* via `https`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I solved it with my hosting provider. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, my hosting provider solved it with .htaccess - I guess I was using it wrong.. Thanks again, Stackoverflow!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```